# AngularJS 2 - Can't load component

Tags: angular

I'm trying to import a component inside 'app.component.ts' which is the main component which will run on the application start.

Here it is a simplified piece of code of app.component.ts.

```
    import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
    import {ContactListComponent} from './contacts/contact-list.component';

    @Component({
        selector: 'my-app',
        template: `Hello`,
        directives: [ContactListComponent],
    })

export class AppComponent {}
```

I get an error on the second import, when I go to browser console I see this error:

[image]

My index.html looks like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Angular 2 application</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
    <!-- IE required polyfills, in this exact order -->
    <script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/router.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.js"></script>
    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script>
        System.config({
            packages: {
                app: {
                    format: 'register',
                    defaultExtension: 'js'
                }
            }
        });
        System.import('app/boot')
                .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/css/app.css">
</head>
<!-- 3. Display the application -->
<body>
<my-app>Loading...</my-app>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have your `ContactListComponent` in a file under the `app/contacts` folder according to the SystemJS configuration you have:

```
app/
 - boot.ts
 - app.component.ts
 - contacts/
   - contact-list.component.ts
```

It seems that your `contact-list.component.ts` isn't located here or there is a problem when transpiled it into the `contact-list.component.js` file.

Comment: my tree folder structure is as you said

Comment: Do you have the `contact-list.component.js` file created from the `contact-list.component.ts` one? (in the same folder)

Comment: No I don't, honestly I don't have app.component.js either, but before trying to import contact-list-component my app was working

Comment: Really? You should! Because you define the `defaultExtension` attribute in the SystemJS configuration...

Comment: I see that you try to import `./contacts/contact-list.component` and the request is `http://.../app/contacts/contact-list-component.js`... That's a bit strange.

Comment: How do I create .js files from .ts ones? I think the problem is because my files aren't transpiled

Comment: In your case, I think that you should use the `tsc` command based on a tsconfig.json file (TypeScript compiler). See this project: https://github.com/restlet/restlet-sample-angular2. To run the compile, you can start this command in background with the `-w` option. Most of time, you have `start` script in your `package.json` file. To start everything (web server and typescript compiler), you can type `npm run start`